# Is it possible to find the record that CustomADODataSet is about to scroll to?

Tags: delphi, dataset, ado

I want to make two datasets, `DS1` and `DS2`, scroll simultaneously. These are actually results of queries on same table with different fields. First one is used for UI and has lots of calculated fields and second one is a simple editable dataset with few data fields. I want both datasets have active record with same `ID`. So, since I assume that `DS1` record set is a subset of `DS2`'s, I just call `DS2.Locate` in `DS2.AfterScroll`. But my assumption can be technically violated (due to bad configuration). So I want to abort the scrolling process of `DS1` when there's no corresponding record in `DS2`. By scrolling process I mean changing active record of `DS1` and firing `DS1.AfterScroll`.

Comment: Have you tried getting DS2 to use the same ADO RecordSet object as DS1?

Comment: @MartynA No, actually I'm not familiar with the trick.

Comment: @saastn You mean if DS1 in recordNo 1 DS2 should in record1 too?

Comment: If I can remind myself how to do it, I'll post an example as an answer if a few minutes.

Comment: @sami if by record 1 you mean first record of dataset then no, but there is an `ID` field in both datasets which is unique and I want to be same in both active records.

Comment: @saastn http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet_MasterSource.html

Comment: @Sami it's not a master-detail scenario, both datasets contain instance of same entity type, they just have different sets of fields.

Comment: So you're asking if something exists so you can detect *pre-scroll* in DS1 where it will end up, so you can position DS2 at the same time? No, there is no such capability. There is no *pre-scroll prediction and broadcast* functionality in ADO.

Comment: @KenWhite is it the provider or it's completely impossible in application side? You think it's bad smell if I expect datasets to scroll simultaneously?

Comment: AFAIK, it's all providers. I know of no DBMS that can foresee the future and tell when and where you're going to scroll a cursor in advance. There is no *see the future* in any provider, and Delphi certainly can't see in advance what you're going to do before you do it. How would any database know before you do it whether you're going to move backward or forward or one or 10 or 100 rows? Think about it.

Comment: Why not check if the ID exists in the BeforeScroll event, and if it doesn't then abort the scroll?

Comment: @JohnEasley in `BeforeScroll` the current record hasn't changed yet, the only thing we know is that we are about to leave this record, there's no clue (that I know) about the destination.

Comment: @KenWhite Well at the very beginning line of `Next` method the dataset knows that it's going to scroll 1 row forward, and after one if clause it'll know if it's possible or not. This is the same for all other methods that change the current record, even `Locate` can be divided into a search process and then a `MoveBy`. This information (the offset from current record) and a clone of dataset would be enough for me. I didn't find it funny or impossible because there are lots of events that follow same logic.

Comment: Remember the current ID of DS1 in before scroll, in afterscroll `Locate` DS2 to the same record. Locate returns True if it succeeds. If it fails, re-locate DS1 to the ID stored in BeforeScroll? In this case, you cannot predict or foresee wether the record of DS1 exists in DS2, you can only check afterwards and restore to a valid state when it doesn't.

Comment: Tnx @R-D, in fact that's what I did at last, plus a flag that shows if `AfterScroll` is called due to relocating back from a wrong state, and some disable/enable controls to prevent flickers and ... I think the whole thing is just a bad idea that I have to live with for a while.

Comment: Sure. The beginning of `Next` knows it's about to move. But it has no information about the row it's going to move to (like an ID), because *it hasn't moved yet in order to get that information*. Again, think about it. *It can't have information about something that hasn't happened yet.* You didn't ask about *an offset from current record*. You asked about keeping them in synch when they may not be the same (*abort when there's no corresponding record*), which means you need to know the contents of the next row before you move to the next row.

Comment: @KenWhite I can scroll in a **CLONE** of `DS1` if I have the offset of " record that CustomADODataSet (`DS1`) is about to scroll to" from current record. This is one way to do it, and I'm asking to see if there're other ways, I'm not sure why do you insist to say that's stupid to access contents of a record before changing the current record, I can understand if someone says that it's not doable because of some technical reason, but it's not something that one shouldn't even think of.

Comment: @saastn that is true, but that's the place to find the next ID, and there are other ways to find it.  Use a cloned dataset, an array, a list... but as Ken has said, there's nothing built-in that can do it for you.  I'd think what we're dealing with here is a bad design..

Comment: @JohnEasley sure, I get it. If you follow the conversation in first response to Ken I just asked if it's either code smell or something that ADO doesn't support. I can't find relation between such question and _foreseeing the future_.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what I understand you to mean, in other words the active record of DS2 tracks the active record of DS1.  The example uses the
`authors` table of the MS demo `pubs` database for Sql Server.  Ideally, it would have an integer primary key ID column, but unfortunately `authors` doesn't.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
  DS1: TADOQuery;
  DS2: TADOQuery;
  DataSource1: TDataSource;
  DataSource2: TDataSource;
  DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
  DBGrid2: TDBGrid;
  DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
  DBNavigator2: TDBNavigator;
  procedure DS1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
protected
  DS2au_id,
  DS2au_lname,
  DS2au_fname : TStringField;
public
end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.DS1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if DS2.Active then
    DS2.Locate('au_ID', DS1.FieldByName('au_ID').AsString, []);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DS1.SQL.Text := 'select * from authors';
  DS2.SQL.Text := 'select au_id, au_name, au_fname from authors';
  DS1.Open;

  DS2au_id := TStringField.Create(Self);
  DS2au_id.FieldName := 'au_ID';
  DS2au_id.Size := 11;
  DS2au_id.DataSet := DS2;


  DS2au_lname := TStringField.Create(Self);
  DS2au_lname.FieldName := 'au_lname';
  DS2au_lname.Size := 40;
  DS2au_lname.DataSet := DS2;


  DS2au_lname := TStringField.Create(Self);
  DS2au_lname.FieldName := 'au_fname';
  DS2au_lname.Size := 20;
  DS2au_lname.DataSet := DS2;

  DS2.Recordset := DS1.Recordset;
end;
```

If you do it this way, the answer to your q

> Is it possible to find the record that CustomADODataSet is about to scroll to?

is that you don't need to.

Comment: Well, it's an interesting technique, but doesn't solve my problem. I really need to work with two independent datasets. But in your solution both datsets have same number of records and `DS2` can only have fields that exist in `DS1`. Your code behaves the same even without `DS2.SQL.Text := ...` line.